# /etc/init.d/openibd: line 147: syntax error near unexpected token `;&'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, infiniband

Hi I am trying to install a fairly lengthy script to install infiniband and the OFED stack on rocks cluster 6.0

here is what i try to run

```
 user@cluster # /etc/init.d/openibd restart
    /etc/init.d/openibd: line 147: syntax error near unexpected token `;&'
    /etc/init.d/openibd: line 147: `if ( grep -i 'SuSE Linux' /etc/issue &gt;/dev/null 2&gt;&amp;1 ); then'
```

can any one share with me a fix or can identify a way to fix the error in this script?
in the file /etc/init.d/openibd

here is the part of the script which contains the error on the indicated line.

```
CONFIG="/etc/infiniband/openib.conf"

if [ ! -f $CONFIG ]; then

echo No InfiniBand configuration found

exit 0

fi

. $CONFIG

CWD=`pwd`

cd /etc/infiniband

WD=`pwd`

PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/bin

if [ -e /etc/profile.d/ofed.sh ]; then

. /etc/profile.d/ofed.sh

fi

# Only use ONBOOT option if called by a runlevel directory.

# Therefore determine the base, follow a runlevel link name ...

base=${0##*/}

link=${base#*[SK][0-9][0-9]}

# ... and compare them

if [ $link == $base ] ; then

RUNMODE=manual

ONBOOT=yes

else

RUNMODE=auto

fi

ACTION=$1

shift

RESTART=0

max_ports_num_in_hca=0

# Check if OpenIB configured to start automatically

if [ "X${ONBOOT}" != "Xyes" ]; then

exit 0

fi

### ERROR ON FOLLOWING LINE ###
if ( grep -i 'SuSE Linux' /etc/issue &gt;/dev/null 2&gt;&amp;1 ); then

if [ -n "$INIT_VERSION" ] ; then

# MODE=onboot

if LANG=C egrep -L "^ONBOOT=['\"]?[Nn][Oo]['\"]?" ${CONFIG} &gt; /dev/null

; then

exit 0

fi

fi

fi
```

Comment: You can't use highlighting within quoted code in markdown. I'll fix it for you. BTW, the script you posted is not indented; was the original code properly indented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got some HTML encoding going on their you need to fix.

Replace `&gt;` with `>`, and replace `&amp;` with `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Your script somehow had all of its > replaced with `&gt;` (and & replaced by `&amp;`, etc)

```
if ( grep -i 'SuSE Linux' /etc/issue &gt;/dev/null 2&gt;&amp;1 ); then

                                                       ^^
```

This is a syntax error because there is no command between the semi-colon that terminates the preceding command and the ampersand. The HTML encoding of certain symbols is confusing the bash parser as a result.